# Compressing data using wavelets with R

Tags: r, wavelet

I'm trying to compress data using wavelets and I wanted to do it with R. Could anyone tell me if there is such a tool?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.rseek.org/?cx=010923144343702598753%3Aboaz1reyxd4&newwindow=1&q=wavelet&sa=Search+functions%2C+lists%2C+and+more&cof=FORID%3A11&siteurl=rseek.org%2F#956

Answer (score 2):

The first step would be a wavelet transform. See (e.g.) the [wavelet](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wavelets/index.html) package.
Once you have your wavelet coefficients, you will need to decide which and how to thresh to achieve compression. Unlike, fourier transforms, using a low-pass filter, will not guarantee any optimality. You could use some arbitrary threshing on the coefficients by trial and error. Here is a reference to a [popular approach](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-34/issue-2/Adapting-to-unknown-sparsity-by-controlling-the-false-discovery-rate/10.1214/009053606000000074.full) motivated by hypothesis testing. You might also want to have a look at the [wavethresh](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wavethresh/index.html) package for more approaches for threshing.
The compression is achieved by storing only the non threshed coefficients. For reconstruction, use the inverse (discrete) wavelet transform.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will be helpful, but a 2007 article in JSS introduces the `waveD` library for `R`.

http://www.jstatsoft.org/v21/i02